# Заменить контент сайта на контент другого сайта

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование

Как сделать так, чтобы при заходе на сайт подгружался другой сайт? Не перенаправление.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery..."></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var url = "https://www.google.ru";
url += "+ajax=true";
$('body').load(url);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Так не получилось

Comment: Для примитивных случаев можно `<iframe>`

Comment: Что пишет в консоли, "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"?

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = "RELOAD"
```

вместо RELOAD соотв. HTML структура сайта. тоже самое можно сделать для `<head>`, `<body>`  и т.д.